# How to extract parent and specific children with XPath

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml

I'm working with the lxml lib on python to extract certain parts of xml documents (rss feeds).
They contain structures as such:

```
<item>
    <title>...</title>
    <description>...</description>
    <other1>...</other1>
    <other2>...</other2>
</item>
```

**My goal is to extract every `<item>` occurrence with his children `<title>` and `<description>`, and not the other children.**
There is always a title tag, not always a description tag.
The order of the children is ***always*** the same.

I thought of doing `//item/descendant-or-self::*[self::item or self::title or self::description]` but it returns obviously *item* as a whole, then *title* and *description* separately.

I do not find axes that could select those elements properly, and since there's not always a description, I can't simply extract `<title>` and `<description>` and add `<item>` and `</item>` manually in a loop.

Is there a way to select `<item>` and these children only?

(edit: bad formatting leading to incomprehensible sentence)

Comment: Didn't understand what you want. Can you provide an example for what you are trying to get?

Comment: yes i want to extract every `<item><title>...</title><description>..</description></item>` with ONLY the title and description of each item. 
Then I write these extracted forms in a text file

Comment: When you say there's not always a description, are you saying that there is no `<description>` tag or that the tag is empty? Is the order of the children of `<item>` always the same? Please edit your question to answer these questions.

Comment: i edited the part about my goal here

Comment: You cannot select `item` without its children. If you are not interested in the children, just ignore them. What information do you want to extract exactly?

Comment: XPath is for *selection*, but what you want is not available for selection.  Your task requires transformation.  Consider XSLT rather than XPath alone, or resolve to write procedural `python` to achieve the effect.